# Pasar esta funcion de JS a Vuejs con laravel

Tags: laravel-5, vue.js

necesito saber si hay alguna manera de pasar esta funcion de JS a Vuejs

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#{{$users->id}}").hover(function(){
        $("{{$users->id}}").css("background-color", "#000000");
        }, function(){
            $("{{$users->id}}").css("background-color", "#C3C3C3");
        });
});
```

Teniendo en cuenta que `<?$user->getObject(user_id)?>` viene desde una Base de datos y desde la misma vista donde se imprime todo, con vue estoy informado que debo pasar las variables al template desde laravel

---

A lo que me refiero

tengo un foreach para mostrar una lista de Usuarios por asi decirlo

```
<button class="btn" style="backgroundColor = "{{$ocupations->color}}" id="{{$users->id">{{$ocupations->ocupation}}</button> //el color en Hex almacenado en la bd

    <lu>@foreach($users as $user)
<li id="{{$user->id}}">{{$user->id}}</li>
<li>{{$user->name}}</li>
<li>{{$user->email}}</li>
@endforeach
</lu>
```

Basicamente me muestra botones n numero de botones, con un color diferente, y el script lo que hara es hacer un hover dependiendo del id y del color, si el color de la primera ocupacion es azul, los usuarios se pintaran de azul, y el color de la segunda ocupacion es amarillo, hara un hover amarillo a los usuarios con la segunda ocupacion

he cambiado un poco el script para que no tengan confusiones

Comment: Vue tiene `props` que puedes mandar desde blade, te recomiendo que en blade uses `{{ }}` en lugar de `<?= ?>`

Comment: Estás haciendo algo que se puede hacer simplemente con `CSS`. Es realmente necesario hacerlo desde `JS`? Podrías asignarle una clase al elemento que te importa, hacer el cambio del color de fondo desde `CSS` y listo.

Comment: @azeós entiendo ese punto pero esta parte son dinamicos los hover que hace, a lo que me refiero es que no es estatico como puedes ver en el ejemplo, sino que conforme agregan elementos toma ese id y despues hace el hover dependiendo del color, puede hacer hover desde 1 boton con color rojo hacer hover a otros 10 del mismo color, en si no es estatica esta parte

Comment: @JonathanOrta Esa parte se entiende pero al pasarlo por los props como vue entiende que cosas debe hacer hover referenciando al id

Comment: Podrías poner un ejemplo de cómo traés la nueva información y cómo la mostrás? Se sigue aplicando lo que digo, en vez de crear de manera dinámica código JS, agregale una clase específica a aquellos elementos que querés que tengan el hover y lo manejás desde CSS.

Answer (score 0):

Como dice @azeos solo necesitas CSS y asignar una clase especifica a cada elemento dinámico.

Algo así:

```css
.effect {
  transition: all .3s ease;
  background: #fff;
  color: #345;
}
.effect:hover {
  background: #0389ff;
  color: #fff;
}
```

Tu HTML quedaria así:

```html
<button class="btn" style="backgroundColor = "{{$ocupations->color}}" id="{{$users->id">{{$ocupations->ocupation}}</button> //el color en Hex almacenado en la bd
<ul>@foreach($users as $user)
<li id="{{$user->id}}" class="effect">{{$user->id}}</li>
<li>{{$user->name}}</li>
<li>{{$user->email}}</li>
@endforeach
</ul>
```

Comment: Es correcto pero no, ya que en laravel Blade se puede asi como lo expones, pero lo necesito traducir para Vuejs, es el porque del titulo. en vuejs tengo estas variables de user y ocupacion en diferentes lados pero no se como hacer el metodo o la funcion para que haga lo mismo que acabas de exponer